# Shellscript is not executing on production server when invoked with c# code on cygwin terminal

Tags: c#, shell, batch-file, imagemagick, cygwin

I have a shell script that I have to run on windows server which is the staging server 
The name of the shell script is 'texteffect'

I have created a batch file named CurveTextEffect.bat that is containing this command

```
@echo on

SET allParameters=%*

C:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -c "%allParameters%"
```

and I am invoking this bat file with this code in c#

Note the whole string is prepared dynamically but final string looks like this

```
string cmd = "CurveTextEffect.bat texteffect -t 'USA BALL' -S 700x -s outline -e concave -d 0.5 -f Impact -p 29.7286291125 -c '#FFFFFF'   -l 0.41289762 -b none 'D:/1.0.0/CurvedImage.png'"
```

here "CurveTextEffect.bat" is batch file name and "texteffect" is the shellscript name

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
    UseShellExecute = true,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
    Arguments = string.Format(@"/C " + cmd),
    CreateNoWindow = false
};

try
{
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Log message in logger
    // Log the parameters and the enviournment path in the logger
    _context.Logs.Add(new Logs()
    {
        LogMessage = ex.Message,
        CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
        LogLevel = Enum.GetName(typeof(LogLevel), LogLevel.Error)
    });
}
```

When I invoke this shell script on the server manually in the cygwin terminal then it's works fine 
Even when I invoke this bat file with arguments it works fine

When I am invoking cygwin terminal into IIS site, which is installed on windows server through the above c# code the it wont work

I have also checked the logs of the IIS where It says texteffect no such command

I have also configured the path of the cygwin and the shellscript in the environment variables as instructed here but then also it says command not found : as done [here](http://im.snibgo.com/cygwin.htm#envvar)

Can some one please help me on that?

I have followed the steps instructed here for installing the Cygwin with ImageMagick
Reference URL:- http://im.snibgo.com/cygwin.htm

When I run this on local IIS it works fine but when it's deployed on staging the shell script does not run

Is any way to identify that shell script is executing on the Staging windows server or not ?

Windows version on the staging site is : Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
I am using this version of ImageMagick-6.9.8-4-Q16-x86-dll.exe [ImageMagick](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imagemagick/)

These are my configured paths in environment variables

```
C:\cygwin64\bin 
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin 
D:\MyScripts
```

Comment: why are you passing a windows batch file to bash ? I do not see the need to involve Cygwin bash at all. Your ImageMagick is a windows tool .

Comment: @matzeri I am executing a shell script that provides me a functionality that ImageMagick does not provide (convert the text & give it an arch effect)

Comment: Try using the absolute path name for texteffect. This needs to be the cygwin path so bash can find the script. In my batch files that start shell scripts, during the dev/debug steps, I have a number of statements that I eventually comment out for prod. These display the current directory and the path in effect as the batch file executes. I always add a setlocal command. I use where <file> and if exists <file> statements as well to make I know if files are found in path or if I have the correct absolute path. 1/2 ...

Comment: 2/2  You may need to remove texteffect from the args to curvetexteffect.bat's parameters and add it into the bash command at run time if it is different between your dev and prod environments. Your batch file will need to figure out the correct location to use. HTH